# Is it possible to see when my Azure Resources are idling?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-rest-api

I want to see when my resources are idling (e.g. certain resources might only be used during business hours and not used for any other background process). I'd like to do that preferably through an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would all depends on the type of resource and what you are wanting to do. You could use the [Azure Monitor API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/) or [Azure Data Explorer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/rest/) with Kusto to query out specific metrics for  your different services. Depending on the type of data, this would require you to have more analytics enabled.

Here are some examples based on types of services.

Azure App Service - You could query for CPU, Memory, HTTP Requests, etc. This would give you an idea of activity. These same metrics tie into the auto-scaling.

Azure VMs - CPU, Memory, Disk IO, etc. You could determine your baseline then you would know when it is idle or not.

Azure Storage - Transactions, Ingress, Egress, Requests, etc. You could use that to determine if there is activity in your storage account.

As you can see it all depends on what you want to define as idling. If the goal is to reduce costs, then that will be difficult with many of these services. You could scale up and down your App Services with some scripts or scale in/out based on metrics. Same can be done with your Azure VMs, or using stopping and starting. Storage will not be able to be adjusted, but you are only charged for storage and egress so that is dictated by activity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not possible. how do you define "idling"? how would azure know if your service does anything or not? besides, most of the PaaS resources cannot be stopped, so whats the use of that.

You can use Azure Advisor to get cost optimization advice, or Azure Monitor directly to gather performance data and then analyze it, but its not going to be trivial.